# Alertmanager to send aggregated/consolidated alert to Webhook

Tags: prometheus-alertmanager

We have some alerts posted by prometheus based on the metrics to our alertmanager.
Currently the alertmanager has the below firing alerts posted to slack-integration:

```
AlertNo.1 - alertname:Alert_Offline, alertsrc:prometheus, cluster_name:cc100, site_name:PP101, device:K8308, timestamp:2021-08-11 00:46:18
AlertNo.2 - alertname:Alert_Offline, alertsrc:prometheus, cluster_name:cc100, site_name:PP101, device:D3010, timestamp:2021-08-11 00:46:18
AlertNo.3 - alertname:Alert_Offline, alertsrc:prometheus, cluster_name:cc100, site_name:PP101, device:X2008, timestamp:2021-08-11 00:46:18
AlertNo.4 - alertname:Alert_Offline, alertsrc:prometheus, cluster_name:cc100, site_name:PP101, device:X2005, timestamp:2021-08-11 00:46:18
AlertNo.5 - alertname:Alert_Offline, alertsrc:prometheus, cluster_name:cc100, site_name:PP101, device:X2202, timestamp:2021-08-11 00:46:18
```

Our alertmanager notifies 5 different alerts due to the 5 unique device names as posted by prometheus. We want to know how we can post only one single/aggregated alert with just cluster_name or site_name label-value to a specific webhook based on the above firing data. Is there a way to post to specific webhook based on a specific label only one alert even though there are multiple due to other unique values in other alerting labels?

Expected:

to slack:

```
<as-above-posted>
```

to a 3rd-party webhook:

```
<only-one-alert-as-below>
AlertNo.1 - alertname:Alert_Offline, alertsrc:prometheus, cluster_name:cc100, site_name:PP101 timestamp:2021-08-11 00:46:18
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using the `group_by` parameter in conjunction with `group_wait` and `group_interval` in your `alertmanager.yml`.

From the [docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/latest/configuration/#route):

```
# To aggregate by all possible labels use the special value '...' as the sole label name, for example:
# group_by: ['...']
# This effectively disables aggregation entirely, passing through all
# alerts as-is. This is unlikely to be what you want, unless you have
# a very low alert volume or your upstream notification system performs
# its own grouping.
[ group_by: '[' <labelname>, ... ']' ]

# How long to initially wait to send a notification for a group
# of alerts. Allows to wait for an inhibiting alert to arrive or collect
# more initial alerts for the same group. (Usually ~0s to few minutes.)
[ group_wait: <duration> | default = 30s ]

# How long to wait before sending a notification about new alerts that
# are added to a group of alerts for which an initial notification has
# already been sent. (Usually ~5m or more.)
[ group_interval: <duration> | default = 5m ]
```

In your case, try something like:

```
group_by: ['cluster_name', 'site_name']
group_wait: 10s
group_interval: 1m
```

`group_by` specifies the labels to aggregate alerts upon.

`group_wait` specifies the amount of time to wait for alerts with labels to add to the aggregated group. In your case, it looks like the alerts come in at the same time, so keeping this value low should be alright, but you can experiment with it to see what works best for you.

`group_interval` specifies the amount of time to wait before sending alerts from an aggregated group that have already been alerted.

Doing so will aggregate your alerts by the specified labels, `cluster_name` and `site_name`, resulting in one fired alert with the [payload](https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/latest/configuration/#webhook_config) containing the list of alerts in the `alerts` section.